# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Signal Processing Stack Exchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Can a causal filter without phase shifts exist?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13970/can-a-causal-filter-without-phase-shifts-exist)

**Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Difference between linear and non linear filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14241/difference-between-linear-and-non-linear-filter)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [A good textbook for designing signal filters](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14016/a-good-textbook-for-designing-signal-filters)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Nyquist Frequency Phase Shift](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14125/nyquist-frequency-phase-shift)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is $O (N \log N)$ FFT speed the fastest we can ever attain?](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13851/is-o-n-log-n-fft-speed-the-fastest-we-can-ever-attain)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Different representations of images and their purpose](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13833/different-representations-of-images-and-their-purpose)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Minimum size for positive samples for HOG (Histogram of Gradient) detector training](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14052/minimum-size-for-positive-samples-for-hog-histogram-of-gradient-detector-train)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Methods to quantify randomness (or complexity) in a signal](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14060/methods-to-quantify-randomness-or-complexity-in-a-signal)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Detecting peaks in a noisy 2D correlation plot](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13793/detecting-peaks-in-a-noisy-2d-correlation-plot)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Need help with FFT results](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/14232/need-help-with-fft-results)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)

---